# Where does ArcMap GUI get font size and docking guide positions from?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, windows-7, font

In the screenshot below, ArcMap 10.1 appears to be making some arbitrary choices about the font to use for:

1. The Layers data frame name in the Table of Contents (larger font than expected)
2. The Main Menu pulldowns (smaller font than expected)

Can anyone tell me where to find a setting that will enable me to make these the same size as the font used for the Main Menu items, please?

[image]

I am using Windows 7 64bit and I know I messed around with Large Icons on the Options tab of Customize | Customize a while back.  I think the small font pulldowns started when I turned them back to normal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you're using Windows 7, you can change this under *> Control Panel > Personalization > Window Color*.

Choose *Item: Icon* and the *Font Size* is what controls the Layers menu size:

[image]

This is handy when doing a demo, to ensure the audience can read the contents easily. (Another useful one to change is *Menu*, so the audience can see what you're choosing in the dropdowns.)

Comment: Thanks Steve - Icon solved the issue with the Data Frame name being too big in the TOC but when I use Menu it alters the menu items and pulldowns together i.e. if I set it to 14pts then the pulldown seems to come up to about 9pts, but if I put it to 10pts then the pulldown goes to about 7pts (as in the original screenshot).  Have you ever seen the menu items and pulldowns use different size fonts?

Comment: Sorry, I can't see how to change just the menu pulldowns. On my PC the menus and their pulldowns are controlled by the Menu option. I suggest the usual Esri fix of reinstalling the OS then ArcGIS :)

Comment: Thanks Steve - I'm hoping to avoid the big stick fix so will give you the points here and try and pursue the odd font size difference via the ArcGIS Discussion Forum.

Comment: Maybe try > Customize > Customize Mode > Reset (on the Toolbars tab)

Comment: Just tried that but to no avail :-(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I'm running arc on parallels and was able to fix it by changing the theme to Window's 7 Basic. The Aero theme mucked it up.

Comment: I am also running ArcMap through parallels and had the same problem. TOC font too large and pulldown font was tiny. As per Maria's answer, changed my theme from Aero to Windows 7 Basic and everything was fixed and displayed proportionately.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  Here you seem to be simply endorsing the answer by @Maria and so it would have been best to upvote that instead of adding another near identical answer.  I will convert your answer to become a comment on that one instead.

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved this in Windows 7 by visiting **Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Display** and **resetting the font size I had set there from 150% to 125%**.  This resolved all.

I was also pursuing the mismatch in font size between Menu items and pulldowns via the [ArcGIS Discussion Forums](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/64720-How-to-reset-Menu-Pulldown-font-size-to-match-Menu-Items).

The problem also affected the docking guides used to help resize windows (see graphic below).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10,

- Click on " Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Display." You will see the part which says "Change only the text size."
- Click on font size and raise it to say '11' and
- Click 'Apply' at the end.