# Size of icons and texts in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, accessibility

I want to increase icons and texts

icons and texts of Toolbar, Table of Contents and Search window is very small!!!

But, Texts in menu-bar is proper size. I don't understand this situation

Now, I use window 10 and arcmap 10.1

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The easy one to fix is the icon size for the buttons on your toolbars.

Use the Main Menu to find Options tab on the Customize | Customize Mode dialog, and tick the **Large icons** checkbox.

[image]

Increasing font size is messier but explained well at https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/31347/115