# Increasing extremely small text in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, accessibility

I'm taking an introductory GIS course and the university provided us with one year student licenses so that we can work from home. The issue is the text in the table of contents and the toolbar(?) (File, Edit, View, Etc.) up top are in very small font; so are the icons and text in the table of contents.

For a while a lot of the toolbar icons were also incredibly small but I figured that out by using the large icon sizes, however the icons are still small within a tool.

[image]

A few months ago I had the same issue with QGIS. I originally deleted the program but since then have redownloaded QGIS and no longer have that issue. To me, this hints at the issue being a laptop problem? I don't know though, just a guess. I'm running windows 10 on an Asus zenbook.

### UPDATE:

Adjusting screen resolution has helped but some icons and text (like in arctoolbox) are still really small:
[image]

I tried referencing these two posts but am still  having trouble:

- [Size of icons and texts in ArcMap?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/197989/size-of-icons-and-texts-in-arcmap)
- [Where does ArcMap GUI get font size and docking guide positions from?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31343/where-does-arcmap-gui-get-font-size-and-docking-guide-positions-from/31347#31347)

Comment: Seems you have a high-resolution monitor used in a low-resolution software support

Comment: @aldo_tapia do you know if there is a way to accommodate for this?

Comment: I've seen this issue in Dell workstations, adjusting screen resolution solves it

Comment: Have you made changes to your laptop display font size options (display settings) ? Sometimes if it's set to more than 100% it messes some applications' UI.

Comment: adjusting the screen resolution does not seem to fix the problem and I've never made changes to my laptop display. Right now my font size is set to the recommended setting of 250% and I tried changing it to 100% but that just makes everything too small to read

Comment: Sorry I guess I could clarify a little bit more: adjusting the screen resolution fixed the text in the menu bar, but it is still really small in arctoolbox (haven't tried others extensively - still learning the software and don't extensively use it yet). Also icons within tools like add data are still really small. I added another picture above